# Excel getting count using macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have many rows of logs like below, need to get count of 'tid' based on 'ServiceReq' from all the rows. Count for the below example for tid 123 is 5. Count for tid 678 is 2.

Can anyone help me for this using excel macros?

[image: Example]

example - sample logs in Sheet1, column A

```
INFO LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “ServiceReq”:”tid”:”123”
INFO LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “ServiceReq”:”tid”:”123”
INFO LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “ServiceReq”:”tid”:”678”
INFO LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “ServiceReq”:”tid”:”123”
INFO LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “ServiceReq”:”tid”:”123”
INFO LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “ServiceReq”:”tid”:”123”
EROOR LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “InitializeREQ”:”tid”:”abc”
EROOR LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “InitializeREQ”:”tid”:”abc”
EROOR LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “InitializeREQ”:”tid”:”abc”
EROOR LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “InitializeREQ”
EROOR LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “InitializeREQ”
EROOR LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “InitializeREQ”
EROOR LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “InitializeREQ”
EROOR LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “InitializeREQ”
INFO LOG Time stamp 2015-06-21-09:56 “ServiceReq”:”tid”:”678”
```

output expected

Servicereq tid count
123 5
678 2

Comment: Could I know what had you tried?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you insist on using a macro for this? I've not tried anything, but it appears that this should reasonable to do with standard spreadsheet functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL function to get the count. 
You may change the code to fulfill your need.

```
Option Explicit
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet


Sub Test()

Dim MyConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim MyRecord As ADODB.Recordset
Dim UnionLastRow As Long
Dim CurrentPointer As Long

Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = WB1.Worksheets("Sheet5")
Set MyConnection = New ADODB.Connection
Set MyRecord = New ADODB.Recordset

' This is the Excel 97-2003 connection string. It should also work with
' Excel 2007 onwards worksheets as long as they have less than 65536
' rows
With MyConnection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    .Open
End With

MyRecord.Open "SELECT COUNT (*) AS MyResult FROM [Sheet5$] WHERE [Logs] LIKE '%“ServiceReq”:”tid”%' GROUP BY [Logs]", MyConnection

ws1.Cells(5, 8).CopyFromRecordset MyRecord
MyRecord.Close

MyRecord.Open "SELECT DISTINCT [Logs] FROM [Sheet5$] WHERE [Logs] LIKE '%“ServiceReq”:”tid”%' GROUP BY [Logs]", MyConnection

ws1.Cells(5, 7).CopyFromRecordset MyRecord

MyRecord.Close
MyConnection.Close

End Sub
```

Below is the print screen of the result:

[image]

Comment: Please take note that you need add the reference : Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library in order for this code to work. Go to code editor > Tools > Reference to add it

Answer (score 0):

You may using `Instr` to solve your problem.

```
Option Explicit
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Sub Test()
Dim Count As Long
Dim Count2 As Long
Dim Pointer As Long
Dim TotalRow As Long
Dim LetterPosition As Long
Dim LetterPosition2 As Long

Count = 0
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet5")

TotalRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Pointer = 1 To TotalRow
LetterPosition = InStr(ws1.Range("A" & Pointer).Value, "“ServiceReq”:”tid”:”123”")
LetterPosition2 = InStr(ws1.Range("A" & Pointer).Value, "“ServiceReq”:”tid”:”678”")
If LetterPosition > 0 Then
Count = Count + 1
LetterPosition = 0
End If

If LetterPosition2 > 0 Then
Count2 = Count2 + 1
LetterPosition2 = 0
End If

Next

ws1.Range("J2").Value = Count
ws1.Range("J3").Value = Count2

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks keong. However the tid is not fixed for 123 and 678. It can be anything  after"tid":, within double quotes. It can be more than 2 as well

Comment: If that was the case, you need using SQL function to get it, i will write it as another answer